# How to get the last focused textbox input when clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I am trying to get the last focused element when pressing my button but Ive had no luck. This is my javascript function:

```
function input(e) {
    e = e.charAt(3);
    $(".textboxclass").each(function(index, value) {
        $(this).val();
        if ($(this).is(':focus')) {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + e);
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
}
```

**and following line is not *working***

```
$(this).is(':focus')
```

when I set alert() before it works.

Thank you.

Comment: provide the HTML that calls on the function `input(e)` as well. We need to know how you're calling this function and how you're passing the `e` variable

Comment: why do you have `$(this).val()` under the first line of your IF conditional? its not doing anything

Comment: $(this).val() is not useful

Comment: I can not understand why your code is not working without HTML part of it, but there is some example, how to find the focused element http://jsfiddle.net/g8ngye8z/1/

Comment: yeah you need to provide more information, a fiddle is always helpful

Comment: `<input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="input(this.id)" />` this is passing on `e` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why its not working is because every time you click the button, your last focused textbox is losing the focus, you need to find another way of doing what you desire. One way I can think of is by using an approach where you store the element focused to a global variable, then use it in yout `if` conditional. Try it out:

```
    var $focused;

    $(".textboxclass").focus(function(){
        $focused = $(this);
    });

    function test(id) {
        e = id.charAt(3);
        $(".textboxclass").each(function() {
            if ($(this)[0] == $focused[0]) {
                $(this).val($(this).val() + e);
                $(this).focus();
            } else {
                console.log("NOT focused");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Ninjin was this able to work for you? let me know